# How to print user-defined environment in scheme?

Tags: scheme, environment

In general I want write code in REPL and sometimes save all defined by myself symbols to file.

For example - after typing in REPL:

```
]=> (define (square x) (* x x))
]=> (define sizes '(5 10 15))
```

I need to call something to receive a list of previously defined objects.
In this case it can be represented in this way:

```
]=> (define get-user-defined-environment 
      (list (list 'sizes sizes) (list 'square square)))
```

To be able then call something like this:

```
]=> (map 
      (lambda (lst) (begin 
         (display "(define ") 
         (pp (first lst)) 
         (pp (second lst)) 
         (display ")\n\n"))) 
      get-user-defined-environment)

(define sizes
(5 10 15)
)

(define square
(named-lambda (square x)
  (* x x))
)
```

And, maybe, save output to file somehow.

So, what could be this **get-user-defined-environment** ?

Comment: Which implementation are you using?

Comment: Packet named dev-scheme/mit-scheme-c, as I understand it is MIT/GNU Scheme.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14184716/1193075

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/a/15064780/1193075

Answer (score 1):

There isn't something in standard Scheme that lets you record the environment.  You can however define your own `define`-like syntax that does it for you.

```
> (define *env* '())
> (define-syntax def&rec
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ name init)
       (define name
         (let ((value init))
           (set! *env* (cons (cons 'name value) *env*))
           value)))))
> (def&rec foo 1)
> (def&rec bar (lambda (x) x))
> *env*
((bar . #<procedure value>) (foo . 1))
```

If you intend to write this to a file, like with the expectation of reading it back in, you will want to record the `init` form, not `value` in the syntax above.  Here is another syntactic form to record the `init`:

```
> (define-syntax def&rec2
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ name init)
       (define name
         (let ((value init))
           (set! *env* (cons (list 'name value 'init) *env*))
           value)))))
> (def&rec2 equal-to (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (equal? x y))))
> *env*
((equal-to #<procedure value>
   (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (equal? x y))))
  (bar . #<procedure value>) (foo . 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to uselpa pointed to [How can find all functions and bounded symbols in an "environment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564030/how-can-find-all-functions-and-bounded-symbols-in-an-environment/15064780#15064780)

(environment-bound-names (the-environment)) - returns a list of user-defined names.

Then (environment-lookup (the-environment) name) - returns value of a name in current environment.

Here is the way:

```
]=> (define (p1 name env) (begin (display "(define ") (pp name) (pp (environment-lookup env name)) (display ")\n\n")))

]=> (define (p2 lst env) (for-each (lambda (name) (p1 name env)) lst))

]=> (p2 (reverse (environment-bound-names (the-environment))) (the-environment))

(define p1
(named-lambda (p1 name env)
  (display "(define ")
  (pp name)
  (pp (environment-lookup env name))
  (display ")\n\n"))
)

(define p2
(named-lambda (p2 lst env)
  (for-each (lambda (name) (p1 name env)) lst))
)
```